# How does passing a block work in ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
class Array
  def new_map!(&block)
    self.replace( self.map(&block) )
  end
end
```

What does self here refer to? How does passing a block work here in simple layman's terms? A concrete example would help.

Comment: Neither `self` is needed here, as the default receiver of both `replace` and `map` is `self`, which will be an instance of `Array`.  That is. you can replace the third line with `replace(map(&block))`.

Answer (score 0):

The `self` refers to the receiver of the `new_map!` method. When you pass a block, it gets turned into a `Proc` and bound to the `block` variable. Then, the expression `self.map(&block)` sends that proc as a block to the `map` call.